# Как добавить кнопку в интерфейс?

Tags: javascript, html, html5, button

Максимально зеленый вопрос. Есть несколько кнопок

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я хочу добавить ещё одну, допустим копию первой.
В HTML коде страницы всё понятно, просто копирую, и вставляю.

Но как это сделать на javascript, не имея JS кода этих кнопок?
Речь даже не про функционал, а просто, как на JS создать кнопку, и "воткнуть" в это место?

Answer (score 1):

После того, как нажмете "Выполнить код", кнопка появится через 2сек.

```js
let container = document.querySelector('#container');

function createButton() {
  let button = document.createElement('button');
  button.type = 'button';
  button.classList.add('styleClass');
  button.id = 'buttonId';
  button.textContent = 'Привет, это кнопка!';

  container.append(button);

  console.log('>>', button);
}

setTimeout(createButton, 2000);
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: То, что кнопку можно создать на JS - понятно, вопрос в том, как её определить именно в то место....

Comment: @FiftyFour7250 в коде выше кнопка вставляется в `<div id="container"></div>` посредством метода `append()`.

Comment: У вас есть div с классом ExtraControls. Смотрите его на предмет childNodes